# Sum of Same Column on Different Conditions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sum

I have a Table like this :

```
 Item  |SubItem| Loc | Type | Qty

 D1    | SD1   |L1  | Type1 | 10

 D1    | SD1   |L1  | Type2 | 10

 D1    | SD1   | L1 |Type 4 |10

 D1    | SD2   |L1  |Type4 | 5

 D1    | SD2   |L1  | Type5| 10

 D1    | SD2   | L1 | Type1 | 10
```

I want three SUM values :

1. Sum all the types for a particular Sub Item & Loc.
2. Sum only type1,4 for a particular SubItem & Loc.
3. Sum of Type1,4 for a particular Item & Loc

   ```
    Item | SubItem | Loc | Sum1 | Sum2 | Sum3 

    D1   | SD1 | L1 | 30 | 20 | 55

    D1   | SD1 | L1 | 25 | 15 | 55
   ```

I have various combination of Items,Subitems,loc in my table.

Comment: Shouldn't Sum3 be 45 as one of the items is Type5?

Comment: Yes 55 is incorrect. It should actually be 35 (type1+type4) of all the Subitems @ particular Loc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code from Boneist i changed the last aggregation to get the correct value in SUM3.

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD1' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type1' TYPE, 10 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD1' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type2' TYPE, 10 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD1' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type4' TYPE, 10 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD2' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type4' TYPE, 5 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD2' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type5' TYPE, 10 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD2' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type1' TYPE, 10 qty FROM dual)
SELECT item,
       subitem,
       loc,
       SUM(qty) sum1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('Type1', 'Type4') THEN qty END) sum2,
       SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('Type1', 'Type4') THEN qty END)) OVER (PARTITION BY item) sum3
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY item,
         subitem,
         loc;

ITEM SUBITEM LOC       SUM1       SUM2       SUM3
---- ------- --- ---------- ---------- ----------
D1   SD1     L1          30         20         35
D1   SD2     L1          25         15         35
```

Comment: Reposting My comments as above : - 

Will this code work if there are multiple Items? Will SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('Type1', 'Type4') THEN qty END)) OVER () not give the addition across all the Items and location present in the table? However I want the sum3 as the aggregation ,of all the Subitems and Locations having Type1&4 ,for a particular Item

Comment: @sqlpractice using partition by - updated answer. Boneist had the answer first in his comment i see, so you should accept his answer if you are satisfied :)

Comment: Thank You. Would you mind explaining me a lil bit here.
Using partition by in sum1 and sum2 gives an error " not a GROUP BY expression"Why cant I use partition by in sum1 and sum2.

I have got the answer to my question but need additional understanding.I would be grateful if you can explain questions like 

Why it is not accepting Partition By in other Sum values ,
How can I select other columns of the table ?
Any alternate way to replace Group by and still get the desired result?

Comment: If you were to type sum(qty) over () sum1, then you would get the error you are talking about. It happens because it doesnt see your function as an aggregate anymore, because you are telling it to sum each row. That is why a sum(sum(qty)) over () would work - (and here partition by is very useful).. Hope my explanation makes sense

Comment: Thank you it does make sense. Can you also help me to understand if there is a way to select other cols alongwith the SUM results above.

Comment: I don't see other columns in the provided data

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily with an aggregate query (including a conditional sum) and an analytic function, like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD1' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type1' TYPE, 10 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD1' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type2' TYPE, 10 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD1' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type4' TYPE, 10 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD2' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type4' TYPE, 5 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD2' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type5' TYPE, 10 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'D1' item, 'SD2' subitem, 'L1' loc, 'Type1' TYPE, 10 qty FROM dual)
SELECT item,
       subitem,
       loc,
       SUM(qty) sum1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('Type1', 'Type4') THEN qty END) sum2,
       SUM(SUM(qty)) OVER () sum3
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY item,
         subitem,
         loc;

ITEM SUBITEM LOC       SUM1       SUM2       SUM3
---- ------- --- ---------- ---------- ----------
D1   SD1     L1          30         20         55
D1   SD2     L1          25         15         55
```

This returns:

- sum1: the sum of qtys for all types for each item, subitem and loc
- sum2: the sum of qtys for types 1 and 4 for each item, subitem and loc
- sum3: the sum of all qtys (actually the sum of sum1s)

That's not what your question said you were after, but it is the expected output that you gave. You should be able to tweak it to get what you really need if it isn't quite what you're after.

Comment: Thank you, I want the sum as shown by you. But there are additional columns in my Table which I don't want to include in the Group By clause. Any way of selecting additional cols along with the Sum values ?

Comment: You would need to update your question to provide more information to make it clear what you’re after. (Eg your sample data only has one item and two sub items; presumably there could be other items; can one sub item belong with different items? Etc etc)

Comment: There can be multiple items and Subitems but one subItem can only be linked to one Item.Other cols as in other attributes of the Items/Subitems which I want to display but these are not to be used in adding up the quantites.

Comment: Will this code work if there are multiple Items? 
Will SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('Type1', 'Type4') THEN qty END)) OVER () not give the addition across all the Items and location present in the table? 
However I want the sum3 as the aggregation ,of all the Subitems and Locations having Type1&4 ,for a particular Item.

Comment: You’d just need to add `partition by item` into the `over ()`. If you’re not familiar with analytic functions, I highly recommend you research them; they’re very handy to know.